# SAX IncrementalParser in Jython

Tags: python, xml, jython, sax

Python standard library provides [`xml.sax.xmlreader.IncrementalParser`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.sax.reader.html#xml.sax.xmlreader.IncrementalParser) interface which has `feed()` method.  Jython also provides `xml.sax` package that uses Java SAX parser implementation under the hood, but it seems not to provide `IncrementalParser`.

Is there *any* way to incrementally parse chunks of XML in Jython?  At the first glance I thought it can be achieved using coroutine like `greenlet`, but I immediately realized that it can’t be used in Jython.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StAX`. The `StAX` parser streams like `SAX` but maintains a cursor and allows you to extract content at the cursor by using `hasNext()` and `next()`.

The following code is adapted from this java example. Note this is my first attempt *ever* with jython, so don't hang me if I did something unconventionally, but the example works.

> > http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html

```
from javax.xml.stream import XMLStreamConstants, XMLInputFactory, XMLStreamReader
from java.io import ByteArrayInputStream;
from java.lang import String

xml = String(
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<employees>
  <employee id="111">
    <firstName>Rakesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Mishra</lastName>
    <location>Bangalore</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="112">
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Davis</lastName>
    <location>Chennai</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="113">
    <firstName>Rajesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Sharma</lastName>
    <location>Pune</location>
  </employee>
</employees>
""")

class Employee:
    id = None
    firstName = None
    lastName = None
    location = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName + "(" + self.id + ") " + self.location

factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()))
employees = []
employee = None
tagContent = None

while reader.hasNext():
    event = reader.next();

    if event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
        if "employee" == reader.getLocalName():
            employee = Employee()
            employee.id = reader.getAttributeValue(0)
    elif event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
        tagContent = reader.getText()
    elif event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
        if "employee" == reader.getLocalName():
            employees.append(employee)
        elif "firstName" == reader.getLocalName():
            employee.firstName = tagContent
        elif "lastName" == reader.getLocalName():
            employee.lastName = tagContent
        elif "location" == reader.getLocalName():
            employee.location = tagContent

for employee in employees:
    print employee
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the sax parser of Java directly.

```
from javax.xml.parsers import SAXParserFactory
factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()

from org.xml.sax.helpers import DefaultHandler
handler = DefaultHandler() # or use your own handler
xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler)
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(streamReader))
```

Comment: It actually is not an _incremental_ parser, but an ordinary event-driven parser.  What I really need is the possibility to feed chunks of XML, without inversion of control (providing a reader callback). E.g.: `parser.feed("<doc>"); do_something_other(); parser.feed("</doc>")`